# Decorator to cache a function result for some time

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, cache

I recently played around with a script that got some data from the Google API. As I didn't want to spam requests at the service (and potentially get blocked), I made this decorator, which caches the result of a function for a specified amount of time. Any call after the time-to-live (TTL) will call the function again.

This is the first decorator I wrote that takes an optional argument (the time to keep the cache). That code was taken from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3931903/4042267) by [@Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243483/eric). I also couldn't abstain from using the new walrus operator (Python 3.8+), since I'm always looking for opportunities to use it in order to get a better feel for it.

Any and all advice on how to make this better or more readable are welcome.

```
from datetime import datetime
from functools import wraps

DEBUG = True    

def temporary_cache(*args, ttl=60):
    """A decorator that ensures that the result of the function call
    is cached for `ttl` seconds (default: 60).

    Warning: The returned object is stored directly, mutating it also mutates the
    cached object. Make a copy if you want to avoid that.
    """
    def decorator(func):
        func.cache = None
        func.cache_time = datetime.fromordinal(1)

        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            if ((now := datetime.now()) - func.cache_time).total_seconds() > ttl:
                func.cache = func(*args, **kwargs)
                func.cache_time = now
            elif DEBUG:
                # for debugging, disable in production
                print("Cached", func.__name__)
            return func.cache
        return inner
    if len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]):
        return decorator(args[0])
    elif args:
        raise ValueError("Must supply the decorator arguments as keywords.")
    return decorator
```

Example usages:

```
import time

@temporary_cache
def f():
    return datetime.now()

@temporary_cache(ttl=1)
def g():
    return datetime.now()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f())
    # 2020-05-12 10:41:18.633386
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f())
    # Cached f
    # 2020-05-12 10:41:18.633386

    print(g())
    # 2020-05-12 10:41:20.635594
    time.sleep(2)
    print(g())
    # 2020-05-12 10:41:22.636782
```

Note that `f` was still cached, while `g` was not, because the TTL is shorter than the time between calls.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the cached function has different arguments?  Or do you only cache functions that don't take arguments?

Comment: @RootTwo: Good question! The decorator allows arguments, but ignores them. This is fine for the usecase I had (a function with no arguments), but in order to generalize it I would have to make `cache` and `cache_time` dictionaries of the arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Rather than using `*args` you can supply a default positional only argument.

  ```py
  def temporary_cache(fn=None, *, ttl=60):
      ...
      if fn is not None:
          return decorator(fn)
      return decorator
  ```
- If you feel following "flat is better than nested" is best, we can use `functools.partial` to remove the need to define `decorator`.

  ```py
  def temporary_cache(fn=None, *, ttl=60):
      if fn is None:
          return functools.partial(temporary_cache, ttl=ttl)

      @functools.wraps(fn)
      def inner(*args, **kwargs):
      ...
  ```
- > for debugging, disable in production

  You can use `logging` for this. I will leave actually implementing this as an exercise.
- > I also couldn't abstain from using the new walrus operator (Python 3.8+), since I'm always looking for opportunities to use it in order to get a better feel for it.

  A very reasonable thing to do. Abuse the new feature until you know what *not* to do. +1

  However, I don't think this is a good place for it.
  Given all the brackets in such a small space I'm getting bracket blindness.
  I can't tell where one bracket ends and the others starts.
- I am not a fan of `func.cache = ...` and `func.cache_time`. You can stop assigning to a function by using `nonlocal`.

Bringing this all together, and following some of my personal style guide, gets the following. I'm not really sure which is *better*, but it's food for thought.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import functools


def temporary_cache(fn=None, *, ttl=60):
    if fn is None:
        return functools.partial(temporary_cache, ttl=ttl)

    cache = None
    cache_time = datetime.fromordinal(1)

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal cache, cache_time
        now = datetime.now()
        if ttl < (now - cache_time).total_seconds():
            cache = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            cache_time = now
        elif DEBUG:
            # for debugging, disable in production
            print("Cached", fn.__name__)
        return cache
    return inner
```

Comment: I was playing around with making `ttl` keyword only, but when preceeded by `*args` it insisted on `args` having to be empty(?). This is a nice way around it. I also previously had `nonlocal`, but liked `func.cache` more because then it is possible to get the value from outside. Didn't know you could assign multiple variables `nonlocal` at once, though!

Comment: @Graipher That sounds strange, I really don't know what was going on there :O I'm not entirely sure why you want to get `func.cache` from the outside, but me understanding isn't really important :) However since you do, might I suggest `inner.cache` over `func.cache`.

Comment: Well, whenever I was using caching decorators in the past, there came the time (during development) where I needed to have a look what was actually in the cache, so it's just convenience, I guess :D